# Watchkit - what exactly should the iPhone app (not the extension) contain?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, watchkit

I don't have a watch so i only work with the simulator.

Let's say i have three apps - one that displays an animation on screen of the watch(several pictures animated) and a few options , also on the watch.

Another one that displays some strings on the watch app , another that displays images on the watch app - both the strings and the images are changed when the user clicks a button.

The code resides on the extension and the resources (images) on the watch app.

Now - what should the iPhone app/screen contain? I want to make the apps as stand alone as possible. Does it need to have an install button or when the user installs it from the app store - the watch app is automatically installed and he can access it from the watch?

I was thinking of only displaying this on the iPhone app/screen : Thank you for downloading the app OR Welcome! and a picture.

Would that be all right according to apple guildelines? What would you advise that the iPhone app/screen should have? Or better yet what do the guidelines suggest?

Should i also include a button for launching the app? What should i include at the minimum? Also what would the code for that look like in swift/what connections should there be?

I am interested in making the watch app experience as stand-alone as possible (can't use watchos2 because i can't publish with Xcode beta).

Lastly - would i need to include an exit button in the watch app (i currently have 2 : next and random for displaying some images)?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Can i set a restriction only for users who have a watch in the app store?

Comment: No, anybody can install the app when you put it in the app store, but the watch features only work when the user has an Apple Watch paired with iPhone.

Comment: That's bad to hear...because i wanted to have a free version for ipads and iphones (without watches) and a paid app for iphone+watch. Is that possible? Your answer would spare me some work implementing ads..

Comment: You can put two apps in the App Store. One free without Watch target, and another one paid with Watch target. That's the only way possible: Two apps. You can name the second one XXX Pro or XXX Plus and name the first one XXX Lite or XXX Free (XXX is your app's real name)